# How to use aggregate SUM function on result of SUM in INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my SQL query which joins two tables:

```
SELECT `o`.`orderID`,
       SUM(i.partialAmount) AS `amount`
FROM   `OrderTable` AS `o`
       INNER JOIN `Item` AS `i`
         ON i.orderID = o.orderID
GROUP  BY `o`.`orderID`
```

Items are connected to orders via 1-to-many relationship. Each item has a partialAmount column and I am adding up those partial amounts to get a total amount per each order.

I would like to get a total amount for all orders though, how to do that?

So I would like something like: SUM(amount) AS `totalAmount` but this doesn't work:

```
SELECT `o`.`orderID`,
       SUM(i.partialAmount) AS `amount`,
       SUM(amount) AS `totalAmount`
FROM   `OrderTable` AS `o`
       INNER JOIN `Item` AS `i`
         ON i.orderID = o.orderID
GROUP  BY `o`.`orderID`
```

I don't want to use WITH ROLLUP - because I don't want an extra row.

Expected output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   orderID       |        amount      |          totalAmount         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1             |          2         |                5             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2             |          3         |                5             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: hmmm ... what's wrong with rollup ?

Comment: Not sure you can get all three of these in one query. The first two columns you are selecting will have multiple rows with multiple different values. The third column you are selecting will have one row with one single value. How would you want this data to be presented to you? Do you want the same value for the third column to be repeated on every row?

Comment: @ajreal ROLLUP is database specific... I want portability.

Comment: so are you looking for a running total or bottom line total?

Comment: @haso84: you should update your question with your expected output.

Comment: @Travesty3 I have updated my question with an expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a total line, you can do something like this code.  There are other approaches as well, depending on how if you need to filter the selected orders

```
SELECT `o`.`orderID`,
       SUM(i.partialAmount) AS `amount`
FROM   `OrderTable` AS `o`
       INNER JOIN `Item` AS `i`
         ON i.orderID = o.orderID
GROUP  BY `o`.`orderID` 
UNION
SELECT 999999,sum(i.partialAmount) as 'Amount'
FROM Item i
```

Comment: Yep, this is about all I can think of, but it might be wiser to `SELECT -1` for the fake orderID. That way you don't run the risk of a collision with an actual orderID of '999999'. Also, don't you have to give the columns aliases in the second `SELECT` query so that the columns match up?

Answer (score 1):

This will be a hit on performance (and assumes that every row from `Item` has an order):

```
SELECT `o`.`orderID`,
       SUM(i.partialAmount) AS `amount`,
       (SELECT SUM(partialAmount) FROM `Item`) TotalAmount
FROM   `OrderTable` AS `o`
       INNER JOIN `Item` AS `i`
         ON i.orderID = o.orderID
GROUP  BY `o`.`orderID`
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly advise doing this kind of thing in the application rather than SQL as it is repitition of work, but it can be achieved as follows:

```
SELECT  OrderTable.OrderID, 
        SUM(PartialAmount) AS Amount,
        TotalAmount
FROM    OrderTable, 
        Item, 
        (SELECT SUM(PartialAmount) AS TotalAmount FROM Item) AS total
WHERE   Item.OrderID = Ordertable.OrderID
GROUP BY OrderTable.OrderID, TotalAmount
```

I can't check the execution plan to compare this to the option of the Subselect posted in another answer by Lamak, but SQL Server definitely optimises the cross apply much better than the subselect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total value on every line you could use sum() over function  which would give you both totals
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

for running total

```
sum(amount) over ()
```

for partial total

```
sum(amount) over (partition by o.orderid)
```

would look like this

```
SELECT distinct `o`.`orderID`,
       SUM(i.partialAmount) over (partition by orderid) AS `amount`,
       SUM(i.partialAmount) over () AS `totalAmount`
FROM   `OrderTable` AS `o`
       INNER JOIN `Item` AS `i`
        ON i.orderID = o.orderID
```

Comment: Does the `over` keyword exist in MySQL?

Comment: @Travesty3 It does not... Even if it did this would return duplicates as it would return one row for every item, not one row for every order.

Comment: I added a distinct to it which should remove the duplicates