# mysql count one value display multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I couldnt find this, i'm sure its simple.

Table (196 rows)

```
tech, name, area, manager
------------------------------
Joe,mary,pa,sally
Kim,brad,ga,tim
kelly,Joe,pa,sally
Joe,jose,pa,sally
```

a tech is assigned to multiple name/area/managers. I want to do a report that shows all the rows of the table with a column showing the number of assignments for the tech.

My desired results

```
tech, name, area, manager, (count of number of tech assignments)
Joe,mary,pa,sally,2
Kim,brad,ga,tim,1
kelly,Joe,pa,sally,1
Joe,jose,pa,sally,2
```

Comment: There are 4 techs, 196 names, 12 areas and 20 managers. My result set should be 196 rows.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you give an example?

Comment: Table
Tech,name,area, manager
Joe, john, PA, Sally
Joe, Mary, GA, Jose

Comment: So it will be select with join to add count column

Comment: I don't get it. If you have 196 distinct names, each with one tech assigned, that tech has exactly 1 assignment in that context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9893602/259457

Comment: yes, but I want to know how many assignments they have total. I can do that independently and I can see each individual assignmnet, I just wanted to combine them.

Comment: See explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you want a subquery on the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT 
   name, 
   area, 
   manager, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE tech = x.tech) AS assignments
FROM tablename x
```

**And here is a possibly more efficient way to do the same thing:**

```
SELECT 
   t.name, 
   t.area, 
   t.manager,
    sub.assignments 
FROM tablename t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tech, COUNT(*) AS assignments 
    FROM tablename 
    GROUP BY tech
 ) sub
ON sub.tech = t.tech
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    a.tech, a.name, a.area, a.manager,
    b.cnt
from table a, (
    select count(*) cnt, tech
    from table
    group by tech) b
where a.tech=b.tech;
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Now that I rewrote my query I realize we're saying the same thing. +1

Comment: @bfavaretto but I like your first solution, it looks tidy.

Comment: Doesnt work, bad syntax, not sure where you are trying to go.

Comment: I think joining a subquery will perform better, as my first solution will always rerun the subquery for each row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tech, count(name) AS total_records FROM db_table GROUP BY tech
```

Not sure this is what you're looking for though.
Oh yeah, looks like you really need to use subquery. 
Thanks for the examples, that helped.

Comment: That's a very sane way to count assignments per tech, but strangely the OP seems to be asking for something else.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, bfavaretto. The time i posted that answer, there were no examples and i misunderstood it :) I've already voted up another answer with subquery method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tech, name, area, manager, assignments  
FROM table
  INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT tech, COUNT(*) AS assignments  
    FROM table  
    GROUP BY tech 
  ) t 
USING (tech)
```

---

***Explanation:***

Select all columns from table and join them with table containing tech column and count of rows from table having particular tech. Keyword USING says how those two table merge.